# vijava after reconfigVM_task, do we need refresh Vsphere web client?

Tags: java, vsphere

**Background:**

In a project, I need use `reconfigVM_task` to delete all the virtualDisks of one virtualMachine, and then, I need continue to run the second `reconfigVM_task` which using other configuration file to add multiple virtualDisks to this virtual machine.

**Problem:**

The firstTask(delete vm's all virtualDisk) works fine, but after that the secondTask(add multiple virtualDisks failed). VCENTER keep showing `"Cannot complete operation, becuase the file or folder [xxxdatastore] vmName/virtualDiskName.vmdk is already exists"`.

I have checked, `vcenterURL`/folder showing the virtualDisk has been deleted already. If I manually refresh vsphere web client, then redo the add virtualDisk, it works.

**Question:**

1. Anyone know how to solve the problem `"Add virtualDisks but has error 'Cannot complete operation because xxx.vmdk already exist"`?
2. OR anyone know how to use `vijava` api to refresh datastore make the delete is able been recognize?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues in the past, where I was not putting `.waitForTask()` at the end of the function call.

If you do that, you shouldn't get any VMDK already exists errors

Comment: Actually I did add .waitForTask(), but it still not works for me.  In the project it needs complete batch of delete disk job and then add  disks jobs in one main thread. Finally I tried reconfigVM_task which one time only do one action(add or delete). Finally it worked. Although I do not very clear about the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you can delete all the disk and add new ones in the single `reconfigVM_task` operation. Just make sure your `VirtualDeviceConfigSpecOperation.remove` operations go first in the `VirtualDeviceConfigSpec[]`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I solve it by each reconfigVM_Task only handle one action(add or delete), it works. You suggestion I tried but part of add operation cannot success. So I simplify the reconfiguration to each time only focus one action, in this way it works for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by focus each of the actions. e.g I need check current `VM1` and `VM2`, `VM1` need delete 2 devices and add 1 new device and `VM2` need delete 1 device then add 1 device.

Before I collect `VM1` and `VM2`'s all delete actions first then collect VM1 and `VM2`'s add actions to reconfigVM_Task's `VirtualDeviceCOnfigSpec[]`. I double checked all `virtualDeviceCOnfigSpec` setting are correct and do have `waitForTask` and other notes mentioned on vmware forum similar issue.

At the end, solve this problem by do `VM1` `delete-reconfig` then `VM2` `add-reconfig`. Then the same to VM2. This time, it works for my project. But the true reason why it failed I did not very clear.